# what is the difference between the words "tall" and "high"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, questions

Are there any differences between the words **"tall"** and **"high"** ?

For instance, *tall building*  and  *high building* 
I'm not sure what are the differences between them.

Comment: I am sorry and don't mean to derogate the question, but the that was the first thing that came to my mind when read the topic only. My own example with "I am". **"I'm high"** and **"I'm tall"** - well there *is* a difference, not sure how to define it though.

Comment: In this case, **tall** is a measurement of length, whereas **high** is a measurement of distance. **Tall** is describing the sum of all points in the height of the building from the ground to the roof. **High** is describing the single height value of the roof in terms of distance from the ground.

An example of where you might need to use high instead of tall: If a primordial dwarf is floating 50 meters above the ground, I would say he is high above the ground, but I wouldn't say he is very tall, because the distance from his head to the ground is != to the distance from his head to his feet.

Comment: When describing a person - high would signify some sort of drug induced reaction.

Answer (score 10):

Tallness is the length of an object that it typically upright -- an absolute measure.  Or it is a relative measure: comparison of such lengths.

Height is a distance "above" an origin position or surface.

Height applied to objects, in particular persons, can mean how tall they are: Tom's height is 6 ft 2 in. The height of the Eiffel Tower is *_*.

But in a context where the *position* of the person or other object is meant, that is, it is not being measured itself but its distance from something else is being measured, height refers to the distance of that position above some base (e.g. sea level -- altitude).

IOW, the meaning of height depends on the context: whether you are measuring a person's body or the distance of the person from something. By default (with no further context), the former is meant.

Although height has these two meanings, "high" does not.  Tom's height is 6'2", but he is not 6'2" high.

"*Tom is higher than Sue*" means that Tom's location is above Sue's. Tom's height on the mountain is greater than Sue's; he has climbed to a greater height.

"*Sue is taller than Tom*" means that the length of her body is greater than the length of his: Sue's height (6'3") is greater than Tom's (6'2").

Comment: A tour guide once showed me a tiny little waterfall that was technically higher than Niagra Falls - because it was halfway up a mountain!

Comment: On the other hand, tall buildings and mountains are sometimes decribed as "high", with exactly the meaning that they are tall. But you'd never say "a high person" to mean "a tall person".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes, sometimes the object is used as a shortcut to stand for its position.

Comment: @Landric: And Mauna Kea is the world's tallest mountain, but not its highest.  Mount Everest is the highest mountain, wrt the position of its peak.

Comment: @Landric: FWIW, Niagara is not particularly high. It is impressive especially by its expanse and the volume of its water. There are other waterfalls in the Eastern US (including in NY State) that are tiny but taller.  And of course there are *much* taller waterfalls west of the Mississippi. The tallest falls east of the Mississippi is less than 300 ft tall.  Yosemite Falls in California is nearly ten times as tall.

Answer (score 2):

"**High** is used for talking about things that are a long way from the ground, or about things whose top parts are a long way from the ground: *a high shelf* ♦ *a high window* ♦ *the world's highest mountain*

**Tall** is used about people or things that measure more than is usual from their bottom to their top, especially things that are more high than wide, like a person or a tree: *a tall lamp-post* ♦ *a tall thin bottle* ♦ *the tallest boy in the class*

You **always** use **tall** when you describe the height of a person: *My brother is taller than me*."

Source: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/high

Answer (score 1):

"Tall" generally refers to the height measured from the ground, and "high" to a point in the air. For instance: Tom is tall. The plane is flying high. 
You wouldn't generally call a building high.

Comment: "Tom is high" means that Tom has been using drugs.

Comment: REALLY?? oh.....ok..!

Comment: There's probably *something* in the distinction you make, but certainly not enough to justify "You wouldn't generally call a building high". Things are [moving in that direction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+high+building+in%2Ca+tall+building+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20high%20building%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20tall%20building%20in%3B%2Cc0), but there are still an awful lot of instances of ***a high building***.

Comment: @Ben: You have a warped mind. Although Dick and Harry are [low church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_church), Tom is high. But they're all churchgoers - not the kind of Tom Dick or Harry who would do drugs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, high mountains.

Comment: @David: Good point - it's invariably the *high mountains of the Alps*, but the [*Tall Trees in Georgia*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A187CscJuGA&feature=kp) (great song, that). You wouldn't often hear *high/tall* reversed in those collocations, even though trees and mountains are "the same" in that we define them both in terms of how *far it is from the ground to the top.*

Answer (score 1):

For chimneys, towers, skyscrapers, trees, people  and anything else you can think whose height is purely vertical, and rises or grows *high* compared to others of its kind; native speakers will tend to prefer: **tall**. Its most common antonym is **short**.

- The [leaning tower of Pisa](http://www.leaningtowerofpisa.net/leaning-tower-of-pisa-facts.html) is only 55.86 meters tall
- I am taller than my sister.
- The giraffe is the tallest animal

For hills; buildings that are wide as well as tall; walls; women heels; and for objects above (without physical contact) the ground use **high**. Its antonym is often **low**.

- Six-inch high heel shoes
- A [**high-rise** building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_with_the_most_high-rise_buildings)
- The ceiling is 4ft high

Sometimes both adjectives can be used to describe the same object and are  both fully acceptable.

> - The world's [**tallest tree**](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2011/04/08/135206497/the-worlds-tallest-tree-is-hiding-somewhere-in-california)
>     is hiding somewhere in California. (...) It's 369 feet **high**

Comment: [A tall/high tower](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+tall+tower%2Ca+high+tower&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20tall%20tower%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20high%20tower%3B%2Cc0). But perhaps when used unattributively (like your Pissa example) _tall_ works better for towers.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use 'high' for things that are wider than their vertical height, for example, high mountains or a high wall.

And we use 'tall' for things that are narrower than their vertical height, like people or trees and etc like eg: Burj Khalifa is the tallest building in the world.